# How can I use the minimal amount of Twitter Bootstrap to get the fluid benefits?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I want my sites to work well on all form factors (phones, tablets, desktop/laptops) and orientations (vertical and horizontal). Twitter Bootstrap's "fluid" example seems great for this. I have to say I'm infatuated with it ... you might even say "Twitterpated"!

Is there a template for an ASP.net (Web Page/Razor) web site (not web app) that incorporates just what I need of the Twitter Bootsrap-o-rama to get this fluidity?

If not, what is the "bare bones" that I must do to implement this? Is it enough to reference the bootstrap .css and .js and then add `class="content-fluid"` and `"row-fluid"` (or whatever they're named exactly) to pertinent tags?

The class declarations (row-fluid, etc.) need only be placed in _SiteLayout.cshtml, stimmt?

Comment: You can use whatever you like. bootstrap-responsive and bootstrap make use of HTML5 elements and Normalize.css, so it even does cross-browser boilerplate for you (just be sure to shiv/shim for IE). Also [see the examples](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples) and view source.

Comment: There is also a responsive variant with bootstrap. Might fit better for you needs.

Comment: http://getpreboot.com/#grid-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably is a template, but the bare minimum you need is

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">Content</div>
    <div class="span6">More content</div>
</div>
```

You don't actually have to use a `div.container-fluid` (though it is the Bootstrap way, and it helps when you view the result on a phone).

You don't have to reference the .js files (they're just for the components). You don't have to include the images; they're just for if you use them, and you can replace them with FontAwesome for better Retina compatibility. You do have to reference `bootstrap.css` though. That's mandatory. :) Though if you download the `.less` source files you can customize what you include (which should include the responsive elements, of course).

Answer (score 1):

you could use twitter bootstrap with asp.net mvc and razor. just plug in the css and script file and write your html as @anthonymills.

Comment: I just searched my hard drive and found 42 copies of bootstrap.js (and that's without deliberately downloading any of them)